# How to start many `Async<'T>` and wait for them one at a time?

Tags: f#, f#-async

I have a little command line app that starts a bunch of expensive computations, and reports some output as they finish. My goal is to run the expensive computations in parallel, but report progress as it's happening.

Right now I'm handling it with `Task`.

```ml
// Tasks eagerly start as soon as they're created
let tasks = lst |> List.map (fun x -> Task.Run(fun () -> expensiveComputation x))
for task in tasks do
  match! task |> Async.AwaitTask with
  // ...
```

`expensiveComputation` is pure, but the body of my `for` loop is not. I print out information as it comes to the user. Note: this does mean that later tasks can "finish" without the user knowing, and it looks like a bunch finish "at the same time" when they get printed. I only really care roughly that progress is shown.

Is there a way to do this without dipping into `Task<'T>`? `Async.Parallel` doesn't work here because it combines everything into one big `Async<'T[]>`. The user doesn't see progress until everything's done.

I feel like this can be accomplished with some combination of recursion but I haven't found it yet.

I understand I have a "working" solution - I'm interested in seeing if this type of behavior is possible as an "F#-native" solution. I'm learning F# and don't want to dip into C#-style code if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eagerly start an `async`, look at `Async.StartChild`.

```ml
let expensiveComputation (x : int) =
  async {
    do! Async.Sleep (x * 1_000)

    return x
  }

async {
  let! jobsRunningInBackground =
    Async.Parallel
      [
        for i = 0 to 4 do
          Async.StartChild (expensiveComputation i)
      ]

  for job in jobsRunningInBackground do
    let! x = job

    printfn $"Completed job %i{x}"

  printfn "All jobs completed"
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: I hadn't considered running `Async.Parallel` on a `list<Async<Async<'T>>>`. This gets me 99% of the way there, but for this to be more like the original `Task` based solution, I'd need the effectful code to be moved out of the list. Can I edit this to include that code?

Comment: I don't think I can give you write access, but I removed the side-effects from the loop. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, it's perfect.